# three dimensional cross product

Tags: vector-spaces

Why do two three dimensional vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $x\cdot y$ does not equal $x\times y$ do not not exist? 
They do not exist right? Please help me kinda lost in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot product is a scalar quantity.  The cross product is a vector quantity.  To compare a scalar and a vector is like comparing apples and oranges--it *really* doesn't make sense to do so.

For example:
$$(1, 0, 0) \times (0, 0, 1) = (0, 1, 0)\\
(1, 0, 0) \cdot (0, 0, 1) = 0$$

You can't really compare $(0, 1, 0)$ and $0$--one is a vector, the other is "just a number."

Answer (score 6):

$x \cdot y$ is a scalar.  $x \times y$ is a vector.  They're not in the same ballpark.  They're not even playing the same game.

Comment: can you give me a little more explanation please?

Comment: I mean...if we're talking about in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $x \cdot y$ is a real number.  Plain ole' ordinary number.  $x \times y$ is another vector.  They're not even the same sort of objects.

It's like asking if there are two cows that can eat grass to make an airplane.

Comment: it is in 3 dimension so it is R^3 right?

Comment: @anonymous: It would help if you showed an example and stayed away from the rest of the type of response. Just some friendly advice. Regards

Comment: can you please show me a example?

Comment: @Amzoti, I thought it explained the problem admirably.

Comment: @jainsmit: What is $(1,0,0) \times (1,1,1)$? What is $(1,0,0)\cdot(1,1,1)$?

Comment: @Amzoti:  I apologize if it sounded offensive!  I was trying to stress the extent to which the two are not comparable.

Comment: @anonymous: No problem. I always try to be understanding of the OP, especially when they are confused about something and are struggling. Just my 2 cents. Regards